# one adjective multiple nouns

Tags: grammar

> At various times, in various situations, they carried M-14s and CAR-15s and Swedish Ks and grease guns and captured AK-47s and Chi-Coms and RPGs and Simonov carbines and black market Uzis and .38-caliber Smith & Wesson handguns and 66 mm LAWs and shotguns and silencers and blackjacks and bayonets and C-4 plastic explosives.

From "The Things They Carried" by Tim O'Brien

Does the word "captured" in "captured AK-47s and Chi-Coms and RPGs and Simonov carbines" modifiy only Ak-47s? Does "black market" in "black market Uzis and .38-caliber Smith & Wesson handguns and 66 mm LAWs and shotguns and silencers and blackjacks and bayonets and C-4 plastic explosives" modify only Uzis? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

That passage is part of a litany describing the variety of things that were carried by American soldiers in the Vietnam war. I don't think you can definitely determine the scope of the adjectives in that list unless you have knowledge of the actual armaments described.
I think it should be read by separating it by the "and"s, and considering each adjective to apply only to what immediately follows it. The author is just trying to express variety.  If he had wanted to, he could have used commas to clarify the scope of the adjectives, but he didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The author intentionally left out commas and repeated "and ... and... and" to give the sense that the soldiers had an overwhelming variety of weapons. This is an example of "poetic license" (or "literary license").

Comment: But wouldn't the ambiguity remain even if there were a comma before every ‘and’?

Comment: The only way to remove ambiguity would be to have a limited number of commas, to separate out the subsets of the series that the adjectives apply to.